# Divisibility Number Theory problem, explanation needed

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving

I can't understand the solution of the following problem:
$x$,$y$,$z$ are pairwise distinct natural numbers show that $(x-y)^5$ + $(y-z)^5$ + $(z-x)^5$ is divisible by $5(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$. No need to explain the div. by 5.

The sol. says:
$(x-y)^5$ + $(y-z)^5$ + $(z-x)^5$ is $zero$ for $x=y$, $y=z$, $z=x$. So the terms $(x-y)$, $(y-z)$, $(z-x)$ can be factored out.

This is the 106th problem chap. 6 form "Problem solving strategies" by A. Engel
If you have alternative solution pls feel free to post it.

Comment: What part of this solution are you unclear about?

Comment: I don't even know what i don't understand. Is solution trying to say that the given polynomial of the 5th degree is $zero$ iff $x=y$ $y=z$ $z=x$ but the polynomial that divides is already in sufficent form. I have some root  of polynomials vibes, but in 3 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the given expression is divisible by $x-y$ if and only if $y$ is a root of the polynomial regarded as a function of $x$. But substituting $x=y$ indeed gives zero, so that $x-y$ must be a factor.

Comment: This is true, but is not an answer, since you assume the very statement that OP seems to be confused by.

Comment: @DonThousand Can you tell me why? He wanted an explanation of the proof of divisibility; I've given him one. I don't see another reasonable explanation of the given solution. His question indicated to me that he simply didn't understand the solution statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x-y=a$ and $y-z=b$.

Thus, $z-x=-(a+b)$ and $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^5=a^5+b^5-(a+b)^5=-5a^4b-10a^3b^2-10a^2b^3-5ab^4=$$
$$=-5ab(a^3+2a^2b+2ab^2+b^3)=-5ab(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2+2ab)$$ and we are done!

Comment: That' s pretty nice. I' ve tried this approach but I haven' t come up with the idea to substitute. Well done.